# IndexError: list index out of range.Line 7

Tags: python

```
m = [[1,2,3],
    [2,1,3],
    [5,4,3]]
for i in range(len(m)):
    for j in range(len(m)*len(m)):
        if i <= len(m) and j <= (len(m)*len(m)):
            m[i][j] <= m[i+1][j+1]
            is_sink = "True"
        if i <= (len(m)-1) and j <= (len(m)*len(m)):
            m[i][j] <= m[i+1][j]
            is_sink = "True"
        if i <= len(m) and j <= ((len(m)*len(m))-1):
            m[i][j] <= m[i][j+1]
            is_sink = "True"
        if i <= (len(m)-1) and j <= (len(m)*len(m)):
            m[i][j] <= m[i+1][j-1]
            is_sink = "True"
        if i <= len(m) and j <= (len(m)*len(m)):
            m[i][j] <= m[i-1][j+1]
            is_sink = "True"
        if i <= len(m) and j <= (len(m)*len(m)):
            m[i][j] <= m[i][j-1]
            is_sink = "True"
        if i <= len(m) and j <= (len(m)*len(m)):
            m[i][j] <= m[i-1][j]
            is_sink = "True"
        else:
            is_sink = "False"
```

I was trying to compare adjacent cells to show the lowest point on a map. Although, it showing out of range, I am not very sure how to express the range properly. I am sure this code can be reduced but this is the best length I can display at the moment.

Comment: The length of any data type is measured on a scale from **0 to number of elements - 1**. Practically, when you reach the third iteration (when J = 2), you try to access m[i+1][j+1] in the first **if statement**, which will be **3**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to solve the problem of minimum value in a matrix **by yourself** (without any other imports), you can easily do it using the following:

```
import random
m = [[1,2,3],[2,1,3],[5,4,3]];
min_value = m[0][0]
for i in range(len(m)):
    for j in range(len(m)):
        if m[i][j] < min_value:
            min_value = m[i][j]
x = random.randint(0, len(m))
y = random.randint(0, len(m))
if m[x][y] == min_value:
    is_min = true;
else is_min = false;
print(is_min)
```

Because you have a square matrix, the **length of columns is the same as the length of rows** (meaning i and j are both in range of len(m))

To choose a random matrix component, you can compute 2 random numbers representing the row and column in the matrix. Then acces that component and compare it with the lowest point in the matrix calculated earlier.

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply, what i am trying to do is find the lowest point then compare all the points in the sublist, then return true or false if lets say a input [0,2] where that is a location. It returns false if its not the lowest point.

Comment: By lowest point you mean the **minimum in all the matrix**? Also, what do you mean by "compare all the points in the sublist, then return true or false if lets say a input [0,2] where that is a location."?

Comment: sorry i meant m[0][2] for example.

Comment: i dont know how to share and edit but i am basically trying to pick any random point and compare it to the "lowest point" if that is the lowest point i want to then return true

Comment: I've included more details in my answer above for you on how to do that.

Comment: hey thanks alot for the reply, this make sense. Just for thinking sake what if to check if an element is the smallest in the sublist but doesnt have to be the smallest in the main list

Comment: The algorithm above does exactly that. It checks step by step each element from the sublists and compares the elements from iteration to the minimum point until then.

Comment: You are welcome! If you found this answer useful, please click the check sign in the upper left side of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not necessarily interested in solving the problem yourself, here is an example using numpy which does that:

```
import numpy as np
m = np.array([[1,2,3],
              [2,1,3],
              [5,4,3]]) 
np.where(m == m.min())
```

For the issue in your code: `j` should go until `len(m)` as well (like `i`). For checking if the indices are out of the matrix, do not forget that python indexing goes from `0` to `n-1` in case you have a list of length `n`.